# Arduino code that causes a Non-const binding error in c++ for CurieBLE

Tags: c++, xcode, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, intel

In an effort to use xcode as my IDE, I am attempting to port the BLE Example code from .ino to .cpp . I am used to minor changes between the ino and cpp language but have been caught off guard by an error, as follows. I'm using the master branch of the core-libs101 library, which I have linked to my xcode cpp project.

In the Arduino LEDExample sketch, the following procedure works:
(Available here: https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/blob/master/libraries/CurieBLE/examples/peripheral/led/led.ino)

```
BLEService ledService(...);
BLECharCharacteristic switchChar(...);

...
ledService.addCharacteristic(switchChar);
```

However, when I try the same thing in .cpp, I get a "non-const lvalue reference to type 'BLECharacteristic' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type  'BLECharacteristic' " compile error. When I change the type of BLECharCharacteristic to BLECharacteristic, and leave everything else the same, there is no compile error.

eg.:
//.cpp code

```
#include "CurieBLE.h"

BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214");
BLECharCharacteristic myFailedChar("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214");
BLECharacteristic myWorkingChar("19B10002-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214");

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //throws compile error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'BLECharacteristic' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'BLECharacteristic'
    ledService.addCharacteristic(myFailedChar);

    //Does not throw compile error.
    ledService.addCharacteristic(myWorkingChar);

    return 0
}
```

I'm more comfortable in embedded C than embedded C++, so this might be an amateur mistake, but I can't wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CurieBLE examples are written for Arduino and the c++ code used is highly coupled with the Arduino environment, don't bother trying to port.